# cmake script mode what is supported and what not

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, rpath

I'm using cmake to build one of my projects, I see the way it installs files is calling a cmake script by `cmake -P cmake_install.cmake`, but the functions used in this cmake file looks different than what is documented, e.g. for shared library install target it has:

```
file(RPATH_CHECK FILE ... RPATH ...)
```

But I cannot find this file sub-command in the [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html), so is there a place that have the available functions to use in script mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an internal command for cmake internal use.

> so is there a place that have the available functions to use in script mode?

The source code is the ultimate documentation https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmFileCommand.cxx#L3757 .

There is no difference in available functions between `-P` and `cmake .` invocations. You can use `file(RPATH_CHECK` in any cmake.

Comment: "There is no difference in available functions between `-P` and `cmake .` invocations." - functions, listed under [Project Commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-commands.7.html#project-commands), are available only for `cmake .` but not for `cmake -P`.